# Android create Custom Object Class with Custom setter getter methods

Tags: android, pojo

I am new in android. I am Implementing application in which I have to generate dynamic list with dynamic title. But I didn't get that how to generate custom Object Class with randomly getting fields.

That means every time Object class fields will change for Single web service call. 
How can I get this ? 
Please Help me.

Comment: please see my question properly. I want to make this pojo class with random fields.

Comment: You could use an ArrayList<Object> and append an arbitrary amount of objects into it by calling yourList.add(something)